# Avoid using exceptions as flow control

Tags: java, coding-style, code-cleanup

I have a sonar violation that sounds like "Avoid using exceptions as flow control."

I wonder what is the best way to rewrite this code accordingly to best practice

```
try { 
} catch(SomeCheckedException ex) {
      throw (SomeRuntimeException) ex.getCause();
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself "why are you checking for the exception", and then specifically check for the exception in code.

Comment: Possibly related: [Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a design smell, the pattern that was recognized by sonar matches your code, which is most likely the case if you are expecting something to happen that will happen in usual flow, and then throw an exception instead of handling the error and providing a proper return instead of throwing another exception to the caller.

One reason this is not optimal is that exception handling is signifcantly slower than simply returning null (for example) in an expected error case. Also your software should provide a clear API which should not be Exception centric.